# Creating a custom transfer function in matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to create a transfer function for a custom equation in order to input the transfer function as a variable into another function. The equation I need to transform into a `tf` is:

```
y = exp(-(x^2))
```

I can't make it work, I tried using:

```
s = tf('s');
H = exp(-(s^2));
```

But I get the following error:

> Error using tf/exp (line 34) The input argument of the "exp" command
>   must be a transfer function of the form -M*s.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You seem to have big problems with the theory behind, it's not a programming problem. First you need to transform `y = exp(-(x^2))` into a function `y(s) = f(s)` - substituting `x` with `s` is not enough, do some research. Finally you will see that your dtransfer function has a form which can easily entered into Matlab.

Answer (score 2):

In MATLAB, `exp(-T*s)` represents a time delay of `T` seconds, which is the only allowable use of the `exp` function in transfer functions in MATLAB (using basic MATLAB and the Control System Toolbox since you mentioned the `tf` function). Since `exp(-x^2)` is not in this form, it does not represent a time delay and therefore is not recognized by MATLAB as a valid transfer function.

If, however the equation `y = exp(-x^2)` is a time domain equation, i.e. `y(t) = exp(-x(t)^2)`, then you first need to convert this equation to `s` domain using the Laplace transform.  However, the Laplace transform of `exp(-x^2)` cannot be represented as a transfer function in MATLAB since it is a nonlinear function.

In either case, you may use linearization to obtain a linear approximation of the exponential term or its Laplace transform and then use that to obtain its transfer function.

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate on how you are passing this transfer function to another function as a variable?  How is it being used in the other function?

If you are trying to just create a generic function, you can do:

```matlab
y=@(x) exp(-(x^2));
```

and then you can do things like `myFunction(y(2))` or if you want to use it as a symbolic expression, you can do:

```matlab
syms s;
y=@(x) exp(-(x^2));
myFunction(y(2+3*i)); %or
myFunction(y(s));
```